# How to make a remote notification conditionally displayed?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

In our app environment, multiple shifts of employees use the same phone. It is possible for our app to receive notifications intended for a prior user. Our notification extension can determine if the notification is for the current user. We'd like to hide the notification if its not intended for the currently logged in user.

Notification Extensions, (UNNotificationServiceExtension) apparently do **not** allow the notification to be hidden. It can be modified but will always be presented to the user.

Why?

Is there a way around this?
I've tried sending silent notifications and generating local notifications. It works, but Apple/iOS starts throttling it after a few notifications and it becomes very unreliable.

Comment: you must handle it in your backend

Comment: It should be handled in backend. Like checking active session before sending notification.

Comment: We do attempt to handle it on the server side, but there are unavoidable cases where it can still slip through that are unacceptable if the user sees it. We can redact but we haven't found a way to completely remove.